# Rails. Renderizar un parcial dentro de otro parcial con tabs

Tags: ajax, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

En mi `show.html.erb` tengo un `nav-pills`. Cada uno de esos "`pills`" tienen un tab-panel. Pues bien, dentro de estos tabs panel suelo poner texto y, hasta ahora, no había probado a renderizar algún parcial.

La funcionalidad de `pills` sí está realizada con `ajax` o `escape javascript`, pero las diferentes `tabs` no, y cuando quiero renderizar cualquier parcial, no me cambia de `tab`, como se puede ver el la siguiente imagen:

[image: Distribución de las <code>tabs</code>]

El código es el siguiente:

#### _tab_leaderboard.html.erb

```
<div id="#leaderboard">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"><b>Public LeaderBoard</b></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab"><b>Group Leaderboard</b></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="col-xs-7">
           <%= render 'competitions/formleaderboard' %>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="col-xs-11">
           <%= render 'competitions/formGroupLeaderboard' %>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Básicamente, me carga los dos render en las dos `tabs`, tanto en la de `public` como en la de `group`.

Lo que quería saber es como hacer para que renderice el parcial según la `tab` que se use, ya que no sé si en un parcial se puede usar `escape javascript` como si fuese una vista normal con su método en el controlador.

## Actualización

Me he dado cuenta de que sólo me carga las `tabs` bien en el `pill` que carga como `active` el código en `show.html.erb` (osea `overview`). Aquí el código donde se cargan:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="competitionContentMenu">
  <li id="overview" role="presentation" class="active">
    <%= link_to "Overview", "#overview", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="data" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Data", "#data", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="discussion" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Discussion", "#discussion", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="leaderboard" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Leaderboard", "#leaderboard", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="more" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "More", "#more", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="nav-tabs-custom" id="detailed_competition">
  <%= render '/competitions/tab_overview' %>
</div>
```

El cambio lo hago con el siguiente código Javascript (`show.js.erb`)

```
if($("#competitionContentMenu li:first-child").hasClass("active")){
  $('#detailed_competition').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/competitions/tab_overview')) %>")
}
if($("#competitionContentMenu li:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active")){
  $('#detailed_competition').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/competitions/tab_data')) %>")
}
if($("#competitionContentMenu li:nth-child(3)").hasClass("active")){
  $('#detailed_competition').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/competitions/tab_discussion')) %>")
}
if($("#competitionContentMenu li:nth-child(4)").hasClass("active")){
  $('#detailed_competition').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/competitions/tab_leaderboard')) %>")
}
if($("#competitionContentMenu li:nth-child(5)").hasClass("active")){
  $('#detailed_competition').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/competitions/tab_more')) %>")
}
```

**En definitiva:** Solo cuando estoy en `Overview` se me cambian las `tabs` correctamente. En las demás me ocurre lo mismo que en lo comentado anteriormente en `Leaderboard` (ya sea haciendo `render`, como un `<p></p>`). Ni en la consola del servidor de rails ni en el navegador se me muestra ningún error.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo (y veo en tu código) ya has generado la información de ambos _tabs_ (podrías verificarlo al ver el código fuente de la página al llamarla en el navegador); si esto es así, entonces el problema es que debes **mostrar** un _tab_ al dar click en la pestaña mientras escondes el otro. ¿Es correcto esto?

Comment: @Gerry Así es. El problema viene que hasta el momento solo he añadido tabs con texto, pero al añadir una que muestre un parcial, es donde no funciona y no me muestra el contenido por separado.

Comment: No veo error alguno en el código que muestras, de hecho intenté reproducir el problema pero no lo logré (es decir, tu código me funciona correctamente). ¿Te muestra algún error en el log del servidor o en la consola del navegador?

Comment: @Gerry, he estado haciendo pruebas, y creo que el error es distinto. Actualizo la pregunta

Comment: ¿Cómo estás cargando el tab overview inicialmente? El código que muestras para _show.html.erb_ no lo muestra. Me parece que por ahí va el problema.

Comment: @Gerry perdón lo omití sin querer. Ahí lo muestro. Sólo que yo lo hago así:  `<%= render '/competitions/tab_overview' %>`. Si lo pongo como tú me dices (`<%= render(partial: 'tab_overview') %>`) no me funciona.

Comment: Es correcto, fue error mío omitir el directorio competitions; ya he actualizado la respuesta. ¿Aún así no te funciona?, ¿tienes algún otro Javascript en el código que pueda estar interfiriendo?

Comment: @Gerry ninguno :(, tiene que haber algo que se me esté escapando, pero no logro ver qué es. Aún muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Veré como lo puedo hacer de otra forma. Si tengo progresos te contaré. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que tengas el `div` con `id="detailed_competition"` de esta forma:

```
<div id="detailed_competition"><%= render(partial: 'competitions/tab_overview') %></div>
```

Así cargará inicialmente el parcial `_tab_overview.html.erb` y después el contenido del `div`  será reemplazado con el parcial que corresponda de acuerdo a la lógica del *show.js.erb*.

Ese es el único cambio necesario que tuve que hacer a tu código para que funcionara; la vista quedó así:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="competitionContentMenu">
  <li id="overview" role="presentation" class="active">
    <%= link_to "Overview", "#overview", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="data" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Data", "#data", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="discussion" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Discussion", "#discussion", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="leaderboard" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Leaderboard", "#leaderboard", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="more" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "More", "#more", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="detailed_competition"><%= render(partial: 'competitions/tab_overview') %></div>
```

---

Como nota adicional, podrías optimizar tu código quitando la lógica de `show.js.erb`, ya que esto provoca que *todos** los parciales se generen (aunque no se muestren) cada vez que cambias el menú (podrás verificarlo si miras el código generado en tu navegador). Lo óptimo (y razón por la que utilizas *ajax*) es que únicamente se genre el código del menú (i.e. `pill`) al que le das clic.

Esto lo puedes lograr pasando una variable a la acción `show` que indique cuál es el `partial` que debe generar; por ejemplo:

show.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="competitionContentMenu">
  <li id="overview" role="presentation" class="active">
    <%= link_to "Overview", "?tab=overview#", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="data" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Data", "?tab=data#", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="discussion" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Discussion", "?tab=discussion#", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="leaderboard" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "Leaderboard", "?tab=leaderboard#", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
  <li id="more" role="presentation">
    <%= link_to "More", "?tab=more#", :remote => true, html_options = "data-toggle" => "pill" %>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="detailed_competition"><%= render(partial: 'competitions/tab_overview') %></div>
```

controlador.rb

```
def show
  @partial = "competitions/tab_#{params[:tab]}"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

show.js.erb

```
$('#detailed_competition').html("<%= j(render(partial: @partial)) %>")
```

Ahora, cada vez que des clic a un elemento (i.e. `pill`) pasará lo siguiente:

1. Se envía el parámetro `tab` con el nombre del `partial` que quieres mostrar.
2. En el controlador recibes el valor del parámetro, le agregas `competitions/tab_` y lo guardas en la variable `@partial`.
3. En la vista `js` únicamente sustituyes el contenido anterior del `div` principal (i.e. `detailed_competition`) con el nuevo, utilizando la variable `@partial` para dinámicamente seleccionar el *template* adecuado.

De esta forma consigues generar sólo el código necesario, optimizando así la carga de cada *tab*.